# Letter combinations of phone dial pad number

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions, combinatorics

In preparation for interviews, I have written a solution to this question:

> Given a sequence of numbers (34128) and an input map such   as a dial
>   pad on a phone (2->[a,b,c], 3->[d,e,f], 4->[g,h,i]) write an algorithm
>   to return all possible words from the sequence. E.g. Input: 232
>   Output: [ada, adb, adc, aea, aeb, aec, afa, afb, afc, bda, bdb, bdc,
>   bea, beb, bec, bfa, bfb, bfc, cda, cdb, cdc, cea, ceb, cec, cfa, cfb,
>   cfc]
>
> Also what will happen if this would have been a 12 digit international
>   number? How would that effect your design.

Below is the solution I have:

```
public class DialPad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(letterCombinations("232"));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> preres = new ArrayList<String>();
        res.add("");

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
            for (String str : res) {
                String letters = map.get(digits.charAt(i));
                for (int j = 0; j < letters.length(); j++)
                    preres.add(str + letters.charAt(j));
            }
            res = preres;
            preres = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return res;
    }

    static final HashMap<Character, String> map = new HashMap<Character, String>() {
        {
            put('2', "abc");
            put('3', "def");
            put('4', "ghi");
            put('5', "jkl");
            put('6', "mno");
            put('7', "pqrs");
            put('8', "tuv");
            put('9', "wxyz");
        }
    };
}
```

Is there any improvement I can make here? It looks to me like complexity is high in this code. How can I simplify this code better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the members of this class in the reverse order (`map`, then `letterCombinations()`, then `main()`) would be more customary.  The `map` should be `private` unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.  I would also avoid creating an anonymous subclass of `HashMap`, and initialize it this way:

```
private static final HashMap<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>(8);
static {
    map.put('2', "abc");
    map.put('3', "def");
    map.put('4', "ghi");
    map.put('5', "jkl");
    map.put('6', "mno");
    map.put('7', "pqrs");
    map.put('8', "tuv");
    map.put('9', "wxyz");
};
```

---

It would be more obvious that `preres` is a temporary variable if you scoped it properly.  Both `res` and `preres` could be named better — I've chosen `results` and `nextResults`, respectively.

Whenever possible, you should specify the initial capacity of an `ArrayList`.  The penalty for underestimating can be rather severe, as it requires reallocating and copying existing results.

`digits.charAt(i)` is a loop invariant that can be moved from the middle loop into the outer one.

All loops should have braces.  Omitting them is bad practice and will cause maintenance-induced bugs.

```
public static List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    results.add("");

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
        String letters = map.get(digits.charAt(i));
        List<String> nextResults = new ArrayList<>(letters.length() * results.size());
        for (String str : results) {
            for (int j = 0; j < letters.length(); j++) {
                nextResults.add(str + letters.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        results = nextResults;
    }
    return results;
}
```

---

It's generally better to return `List<String>` rather than `ArrayList<String>`, to give you flexibility to change the implementation.  For example, here is a solution that uses just one `LinkedList`.

```
public static List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) {
    LinkedList<String> results = new LinkedList<>();
    results.add("");

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
        String letters = map.get(digits.charAt(i));
        for (int j = results.size(); j > 0; j--) {
            String intermediateResult = results.poll();
            for (int k = 0; k < letters.length(); k++) {
                results.add(intermediateResult + letters.charAt(k));
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way we can reduce the complexity  - as of now it is O(n^3) right?

Comment: \$O(n^3)\$ is a gross underestimate. For a `digits` string of length \$n\$, we expect at least \$3^n\$ results — more if `7` is involved. Therefore, the _optimal_ complexity is \$O(4^n)\$.

Answer (score 2):

#### Refer to objects by their interfaces

Something that sticks in the eye is the `ArrayList` and `HashMap` in type declarations.
You should use interface types instead, for example:

```
static List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) { ... }
```

#### Naming

The names are not great.
I guess "res" stands for "results".
"results" is not much longer, but a bit clearer still.
"preres" is not clear at all.

#### Performance

Although your implementation does the job,
keep in mind its weaknesses:

- High memory usage: it accumulates all the combinations in one giant list
- Lots of temporary objects: in the process of building all the combinations, there's a lot of string concatenation, and therefore lots of temporary objects until reaching the completed versions

To improve that,
you would need a completely different algorithm.

To avoid keeping all the results in memory,
you would need a different approach entire,
something that doesn't store all combinations in memory at the same time.

For example, you could use an iterator pattern,
where the iterator spits out the possible combinations in a predefined order, and without accumulating results internally.

Consider this sequence:

> ```
>  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,  ...
> ada, adb, adc, aea, aeb, aec, afa, ...
> ```

You can think of `ada`, `adb`, ... as numbers in a numbering system:

> ```
> a d a
> 0 0 0 = 0
>
> a d b
> 0 0 1 = 0 + 0 + 1
>
> a d c
> 0 0 2 = 0 + 0 + 2
>
> a e a
> 0 1 0 = 0 + 1 * 3 + 0 = 3
>
> ...
>
> a f b
> 0 2 1 = 0 + 2 * 3 + 1 = 7
>
> ...
> ```

The iterator would store its state in a simple counter,
and when a next element is requested,
increment the counter,
and return the string that corresponds to the number in this alternative numbering system.

Note that the counting is *not* base-3.
If all numbers had 3 possible letters,
it would be base-3 and not too complicated.
But some numbers have 4 possible letters.
So, unfortunately, it's quite complicated.

Comment: A complication with the counting system is that `"pqrs"` is four letters, so you it's not quite base 3.

Comment: That's why I never said it's base 3 ;-) I added a note at the end to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the simple route. Basically, I used switch statement first..

```
public static char[] getChars(char s){
    switch(s){
    case '1':
        char[] one = {};
        return one;

    case '2':
        char[] two = {'a','b','c'};
        return two;

    case '3':
        char[] three = {'d','e','f'};
        return three;
    // did this for all...  

    case '0':
        char[] zero = {' '};
        return zero;

    }
    return null;
}
```

Next just perform permutation.. and you're good to go

```
public static void perm(long val){
    perm("",String.valueOf(val));
}

private static void perm(String pre, String sur){
    if(sur.length() == 0){
        System.out.println(pre);
    }else{
        char[] chars = getChars(sur.charAt(0));
        if(chars.length > 0){
            for(char c: chars){
                perm(pre + c, sur.substring(1));
            }
        }else{
            perm(pre,sur.substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an actual review with your second answer.  However, this answer still leans toward code-only.  If you could explain how this is better than the asker's code, then that will really help.

Comment: You've provided an alternative implementation. Since this site is Code Review, could you explain how your solution is better than the original code?

Comment: Basically I think this code is much simpler than the asker's code. Since the asker asked for a simpler implementation. @Jamal